# Sort finished requests by start time

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, data-structures

Given requests that arrive at an unknown time with id: 
1. StartRequest(int id)
2. EndRequest(int id)

I need to return the ids of finished requests with the total time that it took (endTime-startTime) sorted by start time.

Note that if the previous requests are not finished yet the current request is not returned even if it's finished.

I tried the naive way: 
on start request, I add to a List and on end Request, I check if there are requests from the beginning of the list until the first that is not finished and return them.

Is there a more efficient way? Is returning the result on EndRequest the best way?

Comment: It is a very classical sorting, all you have to do is to implement a function that looks like `boolean is_smaller(object1, object2)`. This kind of function is often called 'comparator' . Once this is done, you can implement your sort with a sorting algorithm of your choice, replacing the sign `<` by the function `is_smaller`

Comment: You get the requests already sorted because you can save them on the arrival time. the challenge is to return them when they are finished .. for example if you get requests: A B C and B is finished then you need to wait until A is finished and return A B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following proc in your fav/used languages:

```
public class StartEndRequest {
private static void swap(int [] starts, int [] ends, int i, int j) {
    int temp = starts[i];
    int temp1 = ends[i];

    starts[i] = starts[j];
    ends[i] = ends[j];

    starts[j] = temp;
    ends[j] = temp1;
}
// selection sort ..
private static void sortByProcessTime(int [] starts, int [] ends) {
    for(int i=0; i<starts.length-1; i++) {
        int min = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<starts.length; j++) {
            // swap according to execution time..
            if((ends[j] - starts[j]) > (ends[i] - starts[i]))
                min = j;
        }

        swap(starts, ends, i, min);
    }
}
private static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> getFinishedProcess(int [] prevProcess, int [] starts, int [] ends){
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    for(int i=0; i<prevProcess.length; i++) {
        // add the first operation, it has no prev. operation..
        if(i == 0) {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            temp.add(starts[i]);
            temp.add(ends[i]);

            list.add(temp);
        }
        if(prevProcess[i] != -1) {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            temp.add(starts[i]);
            temp.add(ends[i]);

            list.add(temp);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
private static void blockUnfinishedProcess(int [] preProcesses, int [] starts, int [] ends) {
    for(int i=1; i<preProcesses.length; i++) {
        if(ends[i] == -1) {
            preProcesses[i] = -1;
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // use an auxiliary space to point prev. operations..
    int [] prevProcess = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int [] startReq = {2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5};
    // i am using -1 to indicate unfinished jobs..
    int [] endReq = {7, 4, 3, -1, 8, -1};

    // sort according to execution time..
    sortByProcessTime(startReq, endReq);

    // block those operation whose prev was not finished ..
    blockUnfinishedProcess(prevProcess, startReq, endReq);

    //
    for(int i=0; i<startReq.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(startReq[i]+" -- "+endReq[i]);
    }

    // add only those operation, whose prev also executed successfully.. 
    System.out.println(getFinishedProcess(prevProcess, startReq, endReq));
}
```

}

Comment: A description of the algorithm, in words or in pseudo code, would be more useful. If the OP doesn't know Java, it will be difficult for him to derive any meaning from your code.

Comment: since i am using only basic logic of programming, i don't thing it will be difficult for OP to understand it! still I will remember this in future! thank you!